# Using WinSCP from PowerShell to retrieve files modified within the last hour

Tags: powershell, winscp, winscp-net

I'm using a PowerShell script to retrieve a file from a remote directory. I only want to retrieve a file if it was modified within the last hour. I was able to get the most recent file using the following code:

```
$directoryInfo = $session.ListDirectory($remotePath) 

$latest = 
    $directoryInfo.Files | 
    Where-Object { -Not $_.IsDirectory } | 
    Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | 
    Select-Object -First 1
```

I believe that I need to add another condition to the `Where-Object` clause, but I don't know the proper format. For example,

```
    Where-Object { -Not $_.IsDirectory and <created/modified within the last hour> }
```

How do I do this? Is there a better/simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend you current `where`-block to check if `LastWriteTime` is greater (newer) than a `datetime`-object representing the previous hour. Ex:

```
$lasthour = (Get-Date).AddHours(-1)

$directoryInfo = $session.ListDirectory($remotePath) 

$latest = $directoryInfo.Files | 
Where-Object { (-Not $_.IsDirectory) -and ($_.LastWriteTime -gt $lasthour) } | 
Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
Select-Object -First 1
```

Comment: +1, though not sure if the OP actually wants the `Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1` parts. I can image the intention is to download all recent files, not just the most recent file.

Comment: Yeah, but that wasn't the question. I removed them at first, but since I don't know what he wants to do I added them back in to only fix what he was missing. :-)

Comment: The title says *"retrieve **files** modified within the last hour"*.

Comment: The title isn't the question... The question is how he can filter out old items using the where-statement he has partly written. Either way, it takes him 2 seconds to remove the lines.  :-)

Comment: Also, the question itself actually says he only wants to retrieve "a file". You're probably right, but since the question/title is unclear (mismatch), I decided to answer what he wanted help with and nothing more. We try to avoid writing complete solutions for others as this is supposed to be reusable for others who may not want to download the files, but rather just find the new items. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download all files created/modified within the last hour, use:

```
$directoryInfo = $session.ListDirectory($remotePath) 

$limit = (Get-Date).AddHours(-1)

$recentFiles = 
    $directoryInfo.Files | 
    Where-Object { (-Not $_.IsDirectory) -And ($_.LastWriteTime -Gt $limit) }

foreach ($fileInfo in $recentFiles)
{
    $sourcePath = [WinSCP.RemotePath]::EscapeFileMask($fileInfo.FullName)
    $session.GetFiles($sourcePath, $localPath + "\*").Check()
}
```

Some official [WinSCP .NET assembly examples](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) used to make the code:

- [Downloading the most recent file](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_download_most_recent_file#powershell)
- [Listing files matching wildcard](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_example_listing_files_matching_wildcard)

Comment: I see now that my question and topic are somewhat at odds with one another. My apologies for the confusion. Here is more background:

Comment: Background: We have a process that places one file in the source folder each weekday around 5:20pm. I need to retrieve that file, rename it and put it to another server. The script is scheduled to run on weekdays. My original code worked fine except on Federal Holidays, when no file is created. As a result, the previous days' file would get reprocessed. Thus, I switched to only getting files modified within the last hour rather than getting the most recent file.

Comment: Frode F.'s solution worked as desired. Thanks for all of the help!