# Download files from last 3 days using WinSCP .NET assembly in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, winscp, winscp-net

I have this script and I want to collect all file with extension `*.did` for the last 3 days but it fails with below error.

I don't think that I use correctly the `Get-ChildItem`.

Thanks for your help

```
$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

$file = "*.did"
$localPath = "E:\logs\Log\Arhive\*" 
$remotePath = Get-ChildItem "/C:/logs/*.did" | where{$_.LastWriteTime -le (GetDate).AddDays(-3)}

try {
    # Connect
    $session.Open($sessionOptions)

    # Check exists files
    foreach ($remotePath in $remotePath)
    {
        if ($session.FileExists($remotePath))
        {
            Write-Host "[OK] Log $remotePath exist" -ForegroundColor Green
            # Transfer files

            $session.GetFiles($remotePath, $localPath).Check()
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Host "[X] Log $remotePath NO exist" -ForegroundColor Red
        }
    }
}
finally {
    $session.Dispose()
}

foreach ($file in "E:\logs\Log\Arhive\*.did") {
    if (Test-Path $file) {
        Compress-Archive $file -DestinationPath "E:\logs\Log\Arhive\$inputID.zip" -Update
        Remove-Item $file
    }
}
```

```
(Get-ChildItem : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '/C' does not exist.
At C:\Users\me\Desktop\collectLog.ps1:167 char:15
+ ... emotePath = Get-ChildItem "/C:/logs/*.d ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (/C:String) [Get-ChildItem], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `Get-ChildItem` with remote files.

You would need to use [`Session.ListDirectory`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_listdirectory).
Like here: [Using WinSCP from PowerShell to retrieve files modified within the last hour](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37007929/850848#37010471)

---

But actually, WinSCP can do this for you easily using a [file mask with a time constraint](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask#size_time):

```
$localPath = "E:\logs\Log\Arhive" 
$remotePath = "/C:/logs"
$session.GetFilesToDirectory($remotePath, $localPath, "*.did>=3D").Check()
```